# Flutter - layouts

Tags: android, mobile, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I/flutter ( 8622): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8622): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 8622): BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
I/flutter ( 8622): These invalid constraints were provided to RenderAnimatedOpacity's layout() function by the
I/flutter ( 8622): following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
I/flutter ( 8622):   _RenderDecoration._layout.layoutLineBox (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:819:11)
I/flutter ( 8622): The offending constraints were:
I/flutter ( 8622):   BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter ( 8622): 
I/flutter ( 8622): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 8622): #0      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid..throwError (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:504:9)
I/flutter ( 8622): #1      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid. (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:545:21)
I/flutter ( 8622): #2      BoxConstraints.debugAssertIsValid (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:551:6)
I/flutter ( 8622): #3      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1547:24)
I/flutter ( 8622): #4      _RenderDecoration._layout.layoutLineBox (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:819:11)
I/flutter ( 8622): #5      _RenderDecoration._layout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:857:18)
I/flutter ( 8622): #6      _RenderDecoration.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:987:44)
I/flutter ( 8622): #7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #8      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #9      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #10     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #11     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #12     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #14     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:738:15)
I/flutter ( 8622): #15     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #16     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:738:15)
I/flutter ( 8622): #17     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #18     RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:385:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #20     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:199:11)
I/flutter ( 8622): #21     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #22     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter ( 8622): #23     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:350:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #24     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #25     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter ( 8622): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #27     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #29     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #30     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1206:11)
I/flutter ( 8622): #31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #32     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #34     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #36     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #38     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #40     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #42     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #43     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #44     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #45     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #46     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3030:14)
I/flutter ( 8622): #47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #48     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter ( 8622): #49     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1507:7)
I/flutter ( 8622): #50     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:766:18)
I/flutter ( 8622): #51     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:329:19)
I/flutter ( 8622): #52     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701:13)
I/flutter ( 8622): #53     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:268:5)
I/flutter ( 8622): #54     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:988:15)
I/flutter ( 8622): #55     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:928:9)
I/flutter ( 8622): #56     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:840:5)
I/flutter ( 8622): #60     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:10)
I/flutter ( 8622): #61     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:3)
I/flutter ( 8622): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter ( 8622): 
I/flutter ( 8622): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter ( 8622):   _RenderDecoration#e7960 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):   creator: _Decorator ← InputDecorator ← AnimatedBuilder ← Listener ← RawGestureDetector ←
I/flutter ( 8622):   GestureDetector ← TextSelectionGestureDetector ← IgnorePointer ← Semantics ← TextField ← Row ←
I/flutter ( 8622):   Column ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 8622):   parentData:  (can use size)
I/flutter ( 8622):   constraints: BoxConstraints(unconstrained)
I/flutter ( 8622):   size: MISSING
I/flutter ( 8622): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter ( 8622):   RenderRepaintBoundary#cf635 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):     RenderRepaintBoundary#d2e21 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):       RenderCustomPaint#0795f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):         RenderRepaintBoundary#d5989 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):           RenderPointerListener#c4dea NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):   RenderTransform#4b8f2 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):     RenderAnimatedOpacity#ecabe relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):       RenderParagraph#f9e47 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):   RenderAnimatedOpacity#353ec NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):     RenderParagraph#90160 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):   RenderConstrainedBox#1bf14 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622):   RenderCustomPaint#748f9 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 8622): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderDecoration#e7960 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#503e8 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#9317f relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#d9867 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#f517a relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 8622): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 314 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter ( 8622): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Answer (score 1):

This is most come due to no height given to container or listview. Please check your code for same.

Answer (score 0):

this happens to me when i put a listview inside another listview or any other kind of that because you can't scroll in other scroll without defining which listview to scroll,so you need to put height and width

to solve this problem put your listview inside a Sizedbox like that

```
 ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
            height: 150,
            width: 150,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[],
          ),
        )
          ],
        ),
```

hope that can help you